# Arch Linux on Software RAID, can't find VolGroupArray

Tags: raid, lvm, raid5, arch-linux

I am trying to install Arch Linux on a Software RAID that I am building following their instructions on the [Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_RAID_and_LVM#Create_physical_volumes). I built as far as the Logical Volumes and after that switched to the [Installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide#Mount_the_partitions). I formatted the new partitions (root, var and home) with EXT4 using the guide and rebooted the system. Now when I run `lvdisplay` I can see the volumes (pointing at /dev/VolGroupArray/lv[root|var|home], but when I `ls` the /dev directory, there is no VolGroupArray directory anymore. I'm not sure if there is a command that I'm missing to show it again, or if I screwed something up and have to start over.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer a few minutes after posting here on [this site](http://www.lynuxstuff.com/2011/06/how-to-mark-volume-groups-as-active-or-inactive/). I got to the conclusion as follows:

```
lvscan # Showed all my volumes as inactive, so I assumed I needed to activate them somehow
lvchange -a y /dev/VolGroupArray # Activates all volumes in the VolGroupArray
```